# How can I randomize a string in a 1-D cellular autonama program?

Tags: c++

I am working on a 1-D cellular autonama program, which takes a string of twenty 1's and 0's. Right now, I have a constant string that starts the program the same way every time. My question: How can I randomize the string so that I get a different result every time I run the program? Any help would be appreciated.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bitset>
#include <string>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

const int arrSize = 20;
int numGen = 10;
string Initial = "1001101010110100010";

int main()
{
bitset<arrSize + 2> array(Initial);

for(int i = 0; i < numGen; i++)
{
bitset<arrSize + 2> tempArr(array);

for(int k = arrSize; k >= 1 ; k--)
{
if(array[k])
cout << "1";
else
cout << "0";

int number = (int)array[k-1] << 2 | (int)array[k] << 1 | (int)array[k+1];

tempArr[k] = (number == 3 || number == 5 || number == 6);

}

array = tempArr;
cout << endl;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just build a random string before you start the meat of your program.

```
string generateRandomString(){
    string s = "";
    for(int i=0;i<20;i++){
        if(rand()%2==0) s+="0";
        else s+="1";
    }
    return s;
}
```

Then just put this as the first lines of your main -

```
int main(){
    srand(time(NULL));//Dont forget to seed your randoms!
    Initial = generateRandomString();// btw making the variable Initial capitalzied does not follow convention. 
    ....
```

Also make sure you add the following includes -

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>
```

Comment: Worked Fantastically! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`std::generate_n`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate_n) with a random number generator to fill a string with random bits:

```
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string bits(10, '0');
    std::random_device rd;
    std::default_random_engine eng(rd());

    std::generate_n(bits.begin(), 
                    bits.size(), 
                    [&](){ return eng() % 2 == 0 ? '0' : '1'; });

    std::cout << bits << "\n";  // displays e.g. 1010111110
}
```

If you just want to randomize an existing string of `0`s and `1`s (i.e. preserving the specific distribution of digits but changing their order), then you might find [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) useful:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string bits = "0000011111";

    std::random_shuffle(bits.begin(), bits.end());

    std::cout << bits << "\n";  // displays e.g. 0011010011
}
```

Comment: This won't get the full distribution, however, as it doesn't change the number of 0 or 1 characters.

Comment: @PaulRubel That's true: this is only useful if you want a random string with a specific distribution of 0s and 1s. I'll add a note saying so.

Answer (score 1):

How about this :

```
struct new_str {
    new_str(std::string str )
        : str(str), len(str.size()) { }

    char operator ()() const {
     return str[static_cast<std::size_t>(std::rand() * 
                   (1.0 / (RAND_MAX + 1.0 )) * len)];
    }

    std::string str;
    std::size_t len;
};
```

And then use this in [**`std::generate`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/generate)

```
std::srand(std::time(0));
std::string Initial="1001101010110100010";
std::generate_n(Initial.begin(), Initial.size(), new_str(Initial));
```